# how to configure hostgroup inheritance in Nagios 4.4.5 and display it on Nagios webpage

Tags: nagios

Suppose I have 8 linux servers, among them 4 are db servers and 4 are app servers. I create a linux hostgroup and added 2 inheritance hostgroups linux app servers and linux db servers. But when I reload nagios.cfg and browse nagios web page all the 8 servers are showing under linux hostgroup. How can I display the inheritance hostgroups under linux hostgroup?

I tried the above process by defining like

define hostgroup {
hostgroup_name   Linux
alias            Linux Server
hostgroup_member Linux DB Server, Linux APP server
}

define hostgroup {
hostgroup_name   Linux DB Server
alias            Linux DB Server
}

define hostgroup {
hostgroup_name   Linux APP Server
alias            Linux APP Server
}

But all the APP and DB servers are shown in only Linux hostgroup and no mention of inherited hostgroup in the list.

I want to display on the nagios web page Like:

Linux   (main hostgroup)
Linux DB Servers (inherited hostgroup)
DB Server 1
DB Server 2
DB Server 3
DB Server 4

```
    Linux APP Servers (inherited hostgroup)
      APP Server 1
      APP Server 2
      APP Server 3
      APP Server 4
```

Answer (score 1):

None of your hostgroups have any `members`. Based on your description as I understand it, I would expect to see configuration that looks something like:

```
define hostgroup { 
  hostgroup_name Linux APP Server
  alias Linux APP Server
  members app1,app2,app3,app4
}

define hostgroup { 
  hostgroup_name Linux DB Server
  alias Linux APP Server
  members db1,db2,db3,db4
}

define hostgroup { 
  hostgroup_name Linux
  alias Linux Server
  hostgroup_member Linux DB Server,Linux APP server
}
```

I assume you've configured host group membership on the hosts themselves, but since you don't include this configuration it's not easy to help you.

**edit** I might have misunderstood your question

> But when I reload nagios.cfg and browse nagios web page all the 8 servers are showing under linux hostgroup

This is expected behavior. `hostgroup_member` only includes whatever is in that hostgroup in that host group. It's not a way to include "hostgroups in hostgroups", it's a way to include hosts from a hostgroup in another hostgroup easily.

For more information [see the documentation](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html#hostgroup), specifically:

> **hostgroup_members:** This optional directive can be used to include **hosts** from other "sub" host groups in this host group. Specify a comma-delimited list of short names of other host groups whose members should be included in this group.

It's a common misconception that host groups are objects themselves, when they are in fact just "aliases" for groups of hosts. They do nothing except make it easier for you, so that you can write `app_servers` instead of `app1,app2,app3,app4,app5(...)`.

Comment: I have added the servers under different host cfg file. so no issue there. I want to display multiple hostgroups under a single hostgroup. How can I do it?

Comment: As I clearly stated at the end of my answer, there is no way to include "hostgroups in hostgroups". How different user interfaces choose to represent this might differ, but in Nagios terms a hostgroup doesn't actually include other host groups; it includes the contents of other host groups.